# How to move the train model to production?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have finalized a model and it is performing within acceptable limits. I am using python and scitkit-learn specifically.

Next is to move the model to production.

May I request help to move these models to production. How can I save a trained model in such a way that I can move it to production.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This is a very general questions. I think you should just search the web for some tutorials. However, as a starter, you may want to look into saving your model using Pickle and then serving it as an API using flask.

Answer (score 3):

As the commentor suggested, you should use `pickle`. Specifically for ML, what you're looking for is [Model persistence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html). And with scikit-learn:

> After training a scikit-learn model, it is desirable to have a way to persist the model for future use without having to retrain.

And their example:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> X, y = iris.data, iris.target
>>> clf.fit(X, y)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)

>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(clf)
>>> clf2 = pickle.loads(s)
>>> clf2.predict(X[0:1])
array([0])
>>> y[0]
0
```

> In the specific case of the scikit, it may be more interesting to use joblib’s replacement of pickle (`joblib.dump` & `joblib.load`), which is more efficient on objects that carry large numpy arrays internally as is often the case for fitted scikit-learn estimators, but can only pickle to the disk and not to a string:

```
>>> from sklearn.externals import joblib
>>> joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')
```