# How to reload a regressor in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've completed the training of several regression models for a given dataset, using sklearn. For example, one of them is a `RidgeCV` regressor (3 input features, 2 output features):

```
reg_1 = sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV()
# fit reg_1 ...
print('coef_: {0}'.format(reg_1.coef_))
print('alpha_: {0}'.format(reg_1.alpha_))
```

> coef_: [[0.17864497 0.0852401  0.08863666] [0.17977597 0.09011769 0.08278901]]
>
> alpha_: 10.0

I want to include those fitted regressors in production code, but due to several factors (lot of calls, different instances, training data not available...) I don't want / can't train them again.

How can I reload the existing regressors? I may guess that I have to somehow copy the *private* attributes, but it seems a bit *rude* to do it directly (they are supposed to be private) and I don't know if something else must be done.

PS: the other two regressors are `KNeighborsRegressor` and `LinearRegression`.

Comment: Cant you just pickle (scikit recommends joblib for this) the model and then load them at production? See this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Hope my edition doesn't misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: @VivekKumar yes! that's exactly what I need, thanks! If you wish, please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the valid one. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sraw not at all, thanks. I've just made it clearer respect why I can't retrain it.

Comment: After seeing the question after editing, I would like to close this question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46735954/3374996